# The RunSpace and its closure

Tags: powershell, runspace, powershell-sdk

While working with a script that uses a RunSpace, I found that it takes up more and more system memory. As far as I understand, this is due to the fact that open RunSpace do not close when completed. They remain in memory, accumulating megabytes.

How to close the RunSpace, correctly? However, I do not know how long it will take - 1 second or 1 hour. Closes itself when completed.

As an example, I will give arbitrary scripts.

The first script is how I do the closing of the RunSpace as it is completed (and it apparently does not work).

```
$Array = 1..10000

$PowerShell = [PowerShell]::Create()
$RunSpace = [Runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
$RunSpace.Open()

$RunSpace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable('Array', $Array)
$RunSpace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable('PowerShell', $PowerShell)

$PowerShell.Runspace = $RunSpace

[void]$PowerShell.AddScript({

   # Fill the system memory so that it can be seen in the Task Manager.
   $Array += $Array
   $Array

   # Closing the Process, which should close the RunSpace, but this does not happen.
   $Powershell.Runspace.Dispose()
   $PowerShell.Dispose()
})

$Async = $PowerShell.BeginInvoke()

# Other jobs in the main thread...
```

The second script seems to be more correct, judging by the system memory. However, of course it is not applicable in life, as the `Start-Sleep 10` freezes the main Process.

```
$Array = 1..10000

$PowerShell = [PowerShell]::Create()
$RunSpace = [Runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
$RunSpace.Open()

$RunSpace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable('Array', $Array)

$PowerShell.Runspace = $RunSpace

[void]$PowerShell.AddScript({

   # Fill the system memory so that it can be seen in the Task Manager.
   $Array += $Array
   $Array
})

$Async = $PowerShell.BeginInvoke()

Start-Sleep 10

$PowerShell.EndInvoke($Async) | Out-Null
$PowerShell.RunSpace.Dispose()
$PowerShell.Dispose()

# Other jobs in the main thread...
```

Please write me the correct way to close the RunSpace as it is completed. Thanks you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trying to dispose of a runspace from *within* that runspace sounds like a bad idea - in fact, if I try this in PowerShell Core 7.0-rc2, my session hangs.

It sounds like **you want to dispose of the runspace automatically, *on completion* of the script**.

You can set up an event handler for the [`System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.InvocationStateChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.InvocationStateChanged) event, inside of which you can check for the `Completed` and `Failed` states and close the runspace then:

Note: [`Register-ObjectEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/register-objectevent) must be used to subscribe to the event; while it is possible in principle to subscribe by passing a script block directly to `.add_InvocationStateChanged()` on the `PowerShell` instance, execution will hang when you later call `.EndInvoke()`.

```
# Note: I'm using a small array so that the output of the code better
#       shows what's happening.
$Array = 1..3

$PowerShell = [PowerShell]::Create()
$RunSpace = [Runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
$RunSpace.Open()

$RunSpace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable('Array', $Array)

$PowerShell.Runspace = $RunSpace

$null = $PowerShell.AddScript( {

    # Fill the system memory so that it can be seen in the Task Manager.
    $Array += $Array
    $Array

  })

# Set up an event handler for when the invocation state of the runspace changes.
# Note: Register-ObjectEvent with -Action returns an event-job object, which
#       we don't need in this case.
$null = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $PowerShell -EventName InvocationStateChanged -Action {
  param([System.Management.Automation.PowerShell] $ps)

  # NOTE: Use $EventArgs.InvocationStateInfo, not $ps.InvocationStateInfo, 
  #       as the latter is updated in real-time, so for a short-running script
  #       the state may already have changed since the event fired.
  $state = $EventArgs.InvocationStateInfo.State

  Write-Host "Invocation state: $state"
  if ($state -in 'Completed', 'Failed') {
    # Dispose of the runspace.
    Write-Host "Disposing of runspace."
    $ps.Runspace.Dispose()
    # Note: If the runspace produces *no* output, and you don't
    #       to reuse the $PowerShell / $ps instance later, you
    #       can call $ps.Dispose() right here.
    # Speed up resource release by calling the garbage collector explicitly.
    # Note that this will pause *all* threads briefly.
    [GC]::Collect()
  }      

}

# Kick off execution of the script and
# let the event handler dispose of the runspace on completion.
Write-Host 'Starting script execution via SDK...'
$asyncResult = $PowerShell.BeginInvoke()

# Perform other processing.
Write-Host 'Doing things...'
1..1e5 | ForEach-Object { }

# Finally, get the results from the script execution.
# NOTE: Even though the runspace has likely already been disposed, collecting
#       the results still works, presumably because they're
#       stored in the $PowerShell instance, not the runspace.
Write-Host 'Collecting script-execution results...'
$PowerShell.EndInvoke($asyncResult)

# Note that you'll have to create and assign a *new* runspace to 
# $PowerShell.Runspace if you want to execute further code.
# Otherwise, call $PowerShell.Dispose() to properly dispose
# of the PowerShell instance as a whole.

Write-Host 'Done.'
```

The above should yield the following output:

```
Starting script execution via SDK...
Doing things...
Invocation state: Running
Invocation state: Completed
Disposing of runspace.
Collecting script-execution results...
1
2
3
1
2
3
Done.
```